# Flutter Frontend and Django API for Backend

Tags: django, flutter, django-rest-framework, flutter-layout

Good Day,

I develop Django Applications, now, I want to make android application as well.
Is it possible to create front-end using Only Flutter and use Django REST API for my logic and processing.

I have zero experience in android development, Flutter will be my first entry point.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

yes , you can choose either flutter or ionic , but i recommend you to choose flutter as front end